# Does vmware-tools restart have to be done in ESX as well as guest?

Tags: linux, vmware, virtualization, esx

When restarting the vmware-tools service on the Linux Guest is it necessary to also restart the vmware-tools service on the ESX? I ask because I have 2 other guests running on this ESX/blade.

I'm trying to resolve an obscure issue with SNMP traps not indicating guest health and have to schedule all work accordingly since I manage hundreds of Linux guests on ESX hosts.

Comment: wrong place, off-topic. Should be moved to **ServerFault**

Answer (score 0):

no. and there is no `vmware-tools` service on the ESX. since you are talking about SNMP, the corresponding service should be `hostd`. unless your change does not solve the issue there is no need to restart `hostd`.

Restarting the Management agents on an ESXi or ESX host (1003490)
https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1003490